# Fire Animation from Particle System Does Not Render

Tags: rendering, node-editor, particles, fire

My question is about final rendering. After finally finding what I thought to be the correct node set-up to get my particle system-based smoke and fire animation to work properly, my final hurdle is this:

I can see the flames just fine in the preview render, but, alas! It refuses to render out when I hit that magic Animation render button.

[image: "Smoke Domain" and viewport preview render image of blue flame.]

[image: No fire in final render attempt.]

[image: My current nodes set-up]

Un-checking the "Transparent" box did not solve the issue (and I really would like to have my image frames on a transparent background).

To achieve the effect, I utilized the "Quick smoke" option with a simple circle mesh that emits particles for the fire effect; I just downloaded v2.79b, and am using Cycles Render for this project. Any solutions? Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what I did, but I opened a new Blender file and built the fire animation from scratch—using what I think are the same settings as the previous project—and it renders out just fine now.